# NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ...: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X.'

Tags: ios, swift

in `alarmring.swift` class

```
@IBOutlet weak var label_msg: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let id = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "selectId")as! Int
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var target_object = realm.objects(Alarmof.self).filter("id == %i",id).first  

    label_msg.text = target_object?.msg

}
```

My application is crashing with the following error. What does this mean? How can I fix it?

> terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key lable_msg.'

Comment: my label_msg don't have more then one assignings

Comment: Make sure your outlet is correctly connected to label_msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you link lable_msg in  (**Contention inspector**).

[image]

Comment: i comment "my label_msg don't have more then one assignings" but it have two assignings.....(Delted label's assignings) haha Thnaks for comment